# Is there a way I can simulate a grunt file watcher from the cmd line in the background?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, dos, grunt-contrib-watch

I set up the following task in grunt:

```
   watch: {
        less: {
            files: ["wwwroot/content/less/*.less"],
            tasks: ["less:development"]
        }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can run this from the DOS command line in the background?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to archive. This is the config that the `watch` plugin for Grunt needs to run. You can run it with `grunt watch:less`. What's your intent?

Comment: Yes - Sorry I was not so clear with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you can background a task like this:

```
start /b grunt watch
```

Or in Linux:

```
grunt watch &
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this and it works. But quick question. How can I stop it and is there a way I can list the background tasks running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is `grunt-contrib-watch` which is a grunt plugin working close with grunt. If you JUST want a watch CLI running in NodeJS, you might want to try this [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch)